# UIPath RPA How to get element and text from pdf with password?

Tags: automation, rpa, uipath

I have a pdf file with password. I want to get UI element from this file. But I can not get element.
[image]

After click "Indicate on screen". It select all element on pdf.

Comment: Why is it relevant that the file is password-protected? Do you have troubles opening the file in the first place?

Comment: I using UIPath to read salary file

Comment: The question still isn't clear. Is there an issue opening the file - since it is password-protected? Or, as gaback suggested, do you have an issue getting data from the already opened pdf file (for example some text) - in which case, his or her answer should be considered correct?

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I was open file by command line, and type password with type text. But can't get UI element from the file

Answer (score 1):

UiPath reads .pdf as an image so if you want to get full text of the .pdf then you could use OCR.

Otherwise if you just want a special case then you could do: `recording\basic\Text\Scrape\Scrape Relative`. From there you choose which world(s)/image UiPath has to look for which will always present in the document, then choose location of the word(s) you want to get. Here is the link where you can get more details on `relating scraping` https://studio.uipath.com/v2017.1/docs/relative-scraping